# How to move just one side of bones?

Tags: modeling, bones

[image]

Hello,

Can someon helçp with this? I need to move just the left side of the bones , but the right side moves as well, i have no idea how i activated this. I will add the file in the post

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character still has an active mirror modifier. If you want to solve the problem, select your character, in the properties tab apply the mirror modifier, then shift select the armature, press Ctrl P and choose "with automatic weights".

[image]